# Iterate over large amount of words in Python

Tags: python, performance, hash-map, iteration, edit-distance

I wrote a program that should check a dictionary that contains about 50000 other dictionaries. In those dictionaries, one of the keys has a list of words as value. Now, I iterate over those words, finding the words most similar to a queried input. However, it takes quite a while for it to finish. How can I speed up this process?

```
import pickle,sys

def levenshtein_distance(first, second):
        if first == second: return 0
        elif len(first) == 0: return len(second)
        elif len(second) == 0: return len(first)
        v0 = [None] * (len(second) + 1)
        v1 = [None] * (len(second) + 1)
        for i in range(len(v0)):
            v0[i] = i
        for i in range(len(first)):
            v1[0] = i + 1
            for j in range(len(second)):
                cost = 0 if first[i] == second[j] else 1
                v1[j + 1] = min(v1[j] + 1, v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost)
            for j in range(len(v0)):
                v0[j] = v1[j]

        return v1[len(second)]

def remove_duplicates(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

def main():
    dict_pkld = pickle.load(open('woordjes2.pkl', 'rb'))
    postlist = pickle.load(open('postlist.pkl', 'rb'))
    lowest_distance = []
    words = []
    f = sys.stdin.readlines()
    for line in f:
            woorden = line.rstrip()
            query1 = woorden
            print ('Your query is: "' + query1 + '"')
            print ('A word that is similar to your query is: \n')
            for sub in dict_pkld.values():
                    woorden = sub['termen']
                    if not query1 in woorden:
                            for woord in woorden:
                                    x = levenshtein_distance(query1, woord)
                                    temp_list_number = []
                                    temp_list_word = []
                                    if lowest_distance:
                                            for number, word in zip(lowest_distance, words):
                                                    if number > x:
                                                            #print ('x is kleiner')
                                                            loc = lowest_distance.index(number)
                                                            lowest_distance[loc] = x
                                                            words[loc] = woord
                                                    elif number == x:
                                                            #print ('x is gelijk')
                                                            temp_list_number.append(x)
                                                            temp_list_word.append(woord)
                                                    else:
                                                            #print ('Niks')
                                                            pass
                                    else:
                                            #print ('lijst is leeg')
                                            lowest_distance.append(x)
                                            words.append(woord)
                                    for item, woordje in zip(temp_list_number, temp_list_word):
                                            if not woordje in words:
                                                    lowest_distance.append(item)
                                                    words.append(woordje)


                    else:
                            pass

            words_new = remove_duplicates(words)
            for woordje in words_new:
                    print ('-' + woordje)
            print ('\nThese words have a Levenshtein Distance of ' + str(lowest_distance[0]))

            print ('\nWe are now looking for Tweets that contain the first word of this list: \n')
            result = postlist[words_new[0]]
            for r in result:
                    print (dict_pkld[r]['tekst'] + '\n')


main()
```

> Input: Random word as query, like "`Ajax`"
>
> Output: Is all Tweets in the dictionary that contain a word that is most similar to the query "`Ajax`"

Comment: Could you please add some sample input, and sample output, to help us understand what the code is actually doing? It's kind of hard to read Dutch(?), for someone like me... Even though it's somewhat similar to a combination of German (and English) that some of it is understandable...

Comment: The `open` calls leak without surrounding `with`, although in a one-off script it won't matter. Also, Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3):

- The largest performance problem I see is in the `for woord in woorden` loop. The code iterates over `zip(lowest_distance, words)` - which is growing - over and over again, effectively getting a quadratic performance. I recommend to calculate distances to each `woord`, and sort the resulting list:

  ```
  woord_distance_list = [ (levenstein_distance(woord), woord) for woord in woorden ].sorted()
  ```
- The `words` list undergoes `remove_duplicates`, which is a strong indication that it should be `set` in the first place.
- I would consider delegating `levenstein_distance` to a C function. Python is not sell-suited for such kind of computations.
- Not related to performance:

  - `postlist` is declared way early. Move it down to where it is used:

    ```
        postlist = pickle.load(open('postlist.pkl', 'rb'))
        result = postlist[words_new[0]]
    ```
  - A massive `main` with 4 levels of loop nesting is a strong indication that something is not right. Try to make each loop in a function, just to give it a meaningful name.

Answer (score 0):

- Stay consistent on your indentations levels. Mixing 4 and 8 spaces indent in the same file is not really a good idea. Worse is to do it in the same function.
- Do not call your `main` function freely at the end of the file, guard it with:

  ```
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```
- Make better use of higher-level python functions to reduce cluttering of your code: copying a list is done with `new_list = old_list[:]`, iterating over elements and getting their index is done with `enumerate` and so on.
- Do not write `else: pass` there is no added value, it’s just noise.

Combine that with @vnp words of wisdom to use `set` and order your `woorden` before computing anything, you get:

```
import pickle,sys

def levenshtein_distance(reference, study):
    if not reference: return len(study)
    if not study: return len(reference)
    if first == second: return 0
    v0 = list(range(len(second) + 1))
    v1 = v0[:]
    for i, ref_elem in enumerate(reference):
        v1[0] = i + 1
        for j, study_elem in enumerate(study):
            v1[j+1] = min(v1[j] + 1,
                          v0[j+1] + 1,
                          v0[j] + int(ref_elem != study_elem))
        v0[:] = v1[:]
    return v1[-1]

def levenshtein_query(query):
    def wrapped(word):
        return levenshtein_distance(query, word), word
    return wrapped

def main(words_filename='woordjes2.pkl', tweets_filename='postlist.pkl'):
    dict_pkld = pickle.load(open(words_filename, 'rb'))
    postlist = pickle.load(open(tweets_filename, 'rb'))
    for line in sys.stdin:
        woorden = line.rstrip()
        print('Your query is: "' + woorden + '"')
        words = sorted({
            sorted(map(levenshtein_query(woorden), sub['termen']))[0]
            for sub in dict_pkld.values()
            if woorden not in sub['termen']}) # I wonder why you put this condition in the first place

        print('A word that is similar to your query is:')
        min_distance, most_similar_word = words[0]
        for distance, woordje in words:
            if distance != min_distance:
                break
            print('-', woordje)
        print('These words have a Levenshtein Distance of', min_distance)

        print('Tweets that contain the first word of this list:')
        result = postlist[most_similar_word]
        for r in result:
            print(dict_pkld[r]['tekst'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```